# WebView not launching chrome for external links

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, webview, webviewclient

I am creating a web app which loads a website. I want all the pages on the website loaded within the WebView, but any other links (Google+, Amazon, etc) to trigger Chrome or Browser.

I've tried different variations of setWebViewClient(), but it is continuously loading all pages within the WebView, including Google plus and Amazon.

My code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
myWebView.loadUrl("my.site");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://my.site"))
            view.loadUrl(url);
        else
            return false;
        return true;
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need an intent in the "else" section? If so, how do I do that? intent.putExtra(url); for setting what web address to load in the web browser throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (url.equals("http://my.site"))
```

to

```
if (url.startsWith("http://my.site"))
```

The `String url` parameter is the complete URL, with directory/page#anchor?query etc. etc.